# Can aluminium form blue-colored solution in liquid ammonia?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solutions

I've read that group 1 elements and group 2 elements with  exception of Be form blue-colored solutions in liquid ammonia (Mg requires an electrolytic process). What are the conditions for a metal to form a solution in liquid ammonia, and which metals (other than what I have mentioned) form blue-colored solution in liquid ammonia? Can aluminium also form such solution?

Comment: Blue is the color of the solvated electron. Only the most active metals do that.

Comment: Can Aluminium do that?

Comment: I'd say it is unlikely, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: The textbook blue solvated e- is already difficult to achieve with alkali metals... The answer might practically be yes or no. Written after seeing that is possible according to an answer below and its citation.

Comment: Consistency between question and accepted answer:  If we are allowing an electrolytic process for aluminum, then one should be allowed for magnesium and that works too.  Question edited accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SE answers quoted in the comments provide a good broad answer but with respect to the question of aluminium – aluminium will form a blue solution in liquid ammonia following electrolytic reduction of $\ce{AlI3}$ in liquid ammonia according to [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1950,** *72* (11), 5178–5180](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01167a107).

Europium and ytterbium have also been reported to dissolve in liquid ammonia in [*J. Phys. Chem.* **1956,** *60* (11), 1590–1591](https://doi.org/10.1021/j150545a033).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, aluminium forms a blue colored solution in liquid ammonia. Liquid ammonia will dissolve group 1 (alkali) metals and other electropositive metals such as calcium, strontium, barium, magnesium, aluminum, europium, and ytterbium. At low concentrations (ca. $\pu{0.06 mol/L}$), deep blue solutions are formed: these contain metal cations and solvated electrons. The solvated electrons are stable in liquid ammonia and form a complex: $\ce{[e^-(NH3)6]}$.
For further details see *Chemistry of the main group elements* by Andrew R. Barron on openstax [cnx.org](https://cnx.org/contents/9G6Gee4A@25.9:z9o4a099@2/Liquid-Ammonia-as-a-Solvent).